# Running a LocalDB instance Under Team City Issues

Tags: teamcity, localdb

I'm using localDB for integration tests on a project.  It works fine running tests from Visual Studio 2012.  On the CI server, a TeamCity instance I get an error of

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The sp_configure value 'contained
>   database authentication' must be set to 1 in order to create a
>   contained database.  You may need to use RECONFIGURE to set the
>   value_in_use. Cannot attach the file
>   'C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\6745915c1e8ed3ac\Test.mdf' as database
>   'Test'

I've changed the contained database authentication like it suggested, but still get the error.  Then realized that it is probably running under whatever account the TeamCity Agent is set to run under. I know the LocalDB logs are stored under my user account folder, but I don't know where they'd go if under some system account.  Is this some permissions issue? Would I have to create a contained user for localDB to work on another server/account?